# Webhosting provider where I don't have to transfer my domain?

Tags: web-hosting

I am looking for a web hosting provider where I can keep my existing DNS provider.

All I need is 10k of disk space, and unlimited bandwidth.

I have looked at one.com, but I can't figure out how to just signing on without having to by a domain from them =(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.one.com/en/support/faq/how-do-i-move-my-.com-.net-.org-.info-.biz-.name-domain-to-you

This is what I guess you need

Comment: The crazy thing is that I can't even find where I should sign up without first having to buy a domain from one.com

Comment: It's something that cannot be done automatically, drop them a message asking informations using the contact form https://www.one.com/en/support

Comment: That link has nothing to do with getting hosting from them without transferring your DNS service. In fact, that link talks about transferring the domain registration itself.

Comment: @Andrew My understanding is that she already has her domain and she want to keep just the DNS, so she need to transfer the domain but keep the DNS, and this is a question for the Hosting provider... Am I wrong?

Comment: It's not really related, necessarily... but some hosts who also do domain registration actually make it horribly painful to manage the DNS information, and that link says nothing about that. I typically prefer to keep the registration, DNS and hosting all with separate places myself (and many hosts make it hard to do that, too)